# Typescript - RxJs filter operator type inference with type guard

Tags: typescript, rxjs

**EDIT: It's an IntelliJ issue, VSCode displays it correctly.**
Issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36341

I've got a type guard method:

```
public isValid<T>(result: Result<T>): result is ValidResult<T> {
    return result.isValid()
}
```

the `Result` type is:

```
type Result<T = void> = ValidResult<T> | ErrorResult<T>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to get type inference to work with

```
this.myService
    .getResult(...) // returns Observable<Result<ReadonlyArray<string>>>
    .pipe(filter(Result.isValid))
    .subscribe(result => myFun(result.value)) // here result is "any"
```

Obviously if I specify the generic types, it works as expected:

```
.pipe(filter<Result<ReadonlyArray<string>>, ValidResult<ReadonlyArray<string>>>(Result.isValid))
```

Comment: Seems to work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhwsur?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir let me check if IntelliJ is the problem...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it's IntelliJ, VSCode displays it right. I'll have to open an issue. Btw, thank you for your time